# Последовательный Animator Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В разработке под android новичок, имеется `ImageView`, в который подгружается новая фотография при клике. Хочу, чтобы `ImageView` сначала исчезал, затем подгружалась фотография, затем снова появлялся. Написал такой кусок кода:

```
logo.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500).start();
logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.second);
logo.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(500).start();
```

Мне кажется, что метод `setImageResourse(...)` не дожидается завершения анимации и все накладывается друг на друга, как итог нужного эффекта не получается. Как исправить? P.S. уверен, что решаю слишком в лоб и есть что-то изящнее, если прав, предложите в ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно ваш код выполняет анимацию одновременно, поскольку не задана задержка или какая либо последовательность. Задержку можно задать с помощью метода `setStartOffset(500)`. Либо поставить слушателя на первую анимацию и переопределить метод `onAnimationEnd()`, в котором будет запущена следующая анимация.

Более подробно и с примерами кода можно почитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519682/android-animation-one-after-other)

Также Вы можете использовать набор анимаций `AnimationSet`, в котором можно методом `addAnimation(anim)` набрать несколько анимаций, например перемещение и изменение размеров, и запустить их одной командой `animSet.start();`.

С помощью `AnimatorSet` можно задать последовательность запуска:

```
animSet.play(anim1).before(anim2)
```

Примеры кода [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355495/animation-with-animationset-in-android)